# Equinox start error (console bundle is missed)

Tags: osgi, equinox

```
java.version=1.6.0_10
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
 Command-line arguments:  -console -configuration runtime

ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-03-28 15:50:09.721
 !MESSAGE Could not find bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.console
!STACK 0`enter code here`
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not find bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.console
at          org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.ConsoleManager.checkForConsoleBundle(ConsoleManager.java:211)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:297)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:176)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.main(EclipseStarter.java:151)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-03-28 15:50:09.737
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.main(EclipseStarter.java:151)
```

Comment: This shows how to add the plugins to run configuration http://www.digizol.com/2013/11/Eclipse-org-osgi-framework-BundleException-equinox-console.html

Answer (score 17):

- Go to `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`
- Right click `Run As/Run Configuration/RAP Application/(Select entry point under this tree node)`
- Select `Tab Bundles/`
- Check `org.apache.felix.gogo.command , org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime , org.apache.felix.gogo.shell , org.eclipse.equinox.console`
- Click Add requered Bundles
- Click Validate Bundles ==> `No Problem was detected`
- Apply.

Now run ok.

Answer (score 8):

Console functionality was removed from Equinox system bundle. Now it should be installed explicitly (felix gogo console).

Download [Equinox SDK](http://download.eclipse.org/equinox) and copy such files to your equinox plugin folder:

> org.apache.felix.gogo.command_0.8.0.v201108120515.jar
>   org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.8.0.v201108120515.jar
>   org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.8.0.v201110170705.jar
>   org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.0.0.v20111215-1210.jar

update your config.ini in configuration folder and add such substring to property osgi.bundles

> reference:file:org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.0.0.v20111215-1210.jar@4,reference:file:org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.8.0.v201110170705.jar@4,reference:file:org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.8.0.v201108120515.jar@4,reference:file:org.apache.felix.gogo.command_0.8.0.v201108120515.jar@4,

Comment: Link seems to be broken

Answer (score 3):

This link provides all the details regarding the new console which is based on Apache Felix Gogo shell: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fconsole_shell.htm

In short steps are:

1. Place the necessary bundles in a folder. The bundles are:

   - `org.apache.felix.gogo.command_0.8.0v<version>.jar`
   - `org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.8.0v<version>.jar`
   - `org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.8.0v<version>.jar`
   - `org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.0.0v<version>.jar`
   - `org.eclipse.osgi.jar`
2. Create a `configuration` subfolder put a new `config.ini` file in it with the following content:

   ```
   osgi.bundles=./org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.8.0v<version>.jar@start,\
   ./org.apache.felix.gogo.command_0.8.0v<version>.jar@start,\
   ./org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.8.0v<version>.jar@start,\
   ./org.eclipse.equinox.console.jar@start,\
   osgi.console.enable.builtin=false
   osgi.console=<port>
   ```
3. Start the Equinox framework with this command:

   ```
   java -jar org.eclipse.osgi.jar
   ```

Answer (score 2):

In the above `config.ini` `osgi.console.enable.builtin=false` must NOT be on the same line with the `osgi.bundles` property. The official documentation seems to have this wrong too.

My `config.ini` looks like:

```
osgi.bundles=./org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.10.0.v201209301036.jar@start,\
./org.apache.felix.gogo.command_0.10.0.v201209301215.jar@start,\
./org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.10.0.v201212101605.jar@start,\
./org.eclipse.equinox.console.jar@start
osgi.console.enable.builtin=false
osgi.console=4711
```

Answer (score 0):

Necessary bundles are missing.
Add them in run as->run configurations->osgi framework->bundles
Add following bundles along with your own bundles and delete others:
org.apache.felix.gogo.command_0.8.0.v201108120515.jar

org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.8.0.v201108120515.jar

org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.8.0.v201110170705.jar

org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.0.0.v20111215-1210.jar

then click apply and run.