# Standalone OSGi (Equinox) server  on Eclipse Juno

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, osgi

I'm trying to get the osgi server from the Eclipse Juno Release and run it standalone. Some old tutorials say that just grabbing the `org.eclipse.osgi_VERSION.jar` is enough to start it from the command line as

```
java -jar  org.eclipse.osgi_VERSION.jar -console
```

When I try that, it doesn't show the prompt as expected, but instead sits quietly as if waiting for something to happen.

However, I can comfortably start and install bundles by doing a  `./eclipse -console`, which obviously isn't an option when running on the server, where I want to deploy bundles at runtime.

Some googling revealed I need to gather up jars (even Apache Felix's gogo) from here and there, but couldn't find anything concrete that would allow me to run this thing in a "headless" fashion.

Is there a way to do this in a clean and simple way, or would you suggest shifting to Apache Felix?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905607/equinox-start-error-console-bundle-is-missed) seems related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try Apache karaf. It can run with Felix or Equinox and contains everything you need for a decent OSGi server. See http://karaf.apache.org/

Comment: Well to be honest, this is what I resorted to at the end! @Christian Schneider I'm looking through your posts right now ...

Answer (score 12):

Equinox in Juno does no longer contain the console out of the box. It's now contained in a separate bundle which implements the Equinox console on top of the Apache GoGo shell.

Thus, the minimum setup of bundles for running Equinox *including the console* is:

- org.eclipse.osgi
- org.eclipse.equinox.console
- org.apache.felifx.gogo.command
- org.apache.felifx.gogo.runtime
- org.apache.felifx.gogo.shell

For running the SSH console one also needs:

- org.eclipse.equinox.console.ssh
- org.apache.mina.core
- org.apache.sshd.core

Additionally, you need to use *a different configuration area*. Equinox reads settings (like what bundles to use, their start levels, what application to start, etc.) from the config.ini. Thus, as along as you use the same configuration area as Juno you'll always end up in your Juno environment. You may corrupt your Juno installation when modifying the config.ini directly.

A better start is to download the Equinox Juno OSGi starter kit:

- http://download.eclipse.org/equinox/drops/R-3.8-201206081400/index.php

You can also try one of the OSGi Equinox server distributions:

- http://www.eclipse.org/virgo/
- http://www.eclipse.org/gyrex/

Comment: The Juno OSGi starter kit is basically the same jar that org.eclipse.osgi_VERSION.jar. After much consideration I decided to move away from Equinox to Felix(actually to Karaf) - mainly because of human maintenance issues for our project needs, than on anything else. But thanks for your answer, it definitely helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
java -classpath ./plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
    org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main -console
```

Comment: that does not run the sever alone ... starts up eclipse along with it too. Thanks for answering though ..

Answer (score 0):

This link provides all the details regarding the new console which is based on Apache Felix Gogo shell: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fconsole_shell.htm

In short steps are:

1. Place the necessary bundles in a folder. The bundles are:
   org.apache.felix.gogo.command_0.8.0v.jar
   org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.8.0v.jar
   org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.8.0v.jar
   org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.0.0v.jar
   org.eclipse.osgi.jar
2. Create a configuration subfolder and a config.ini file with the following content

   osgi.bundles=./org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.8.0v.jar@start,\
   ./org.apache.felix.gogo.command_0.8.0v.jar@start,\
   ./org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.8.0v.jar@start,\
   ./org.eclipse.equinox.console.jar@start,\
   osgi.console.enable.builtin=false
3. Start the Equinox framework with the below command: 
   java -jar org.eclipse.osgi.jar

Answer (score 0):

To run with the old console, you can invoke:

`java -Dosgi.console.enable.builtin=true -jar org.eclipse.osgi_VERSION.jar -console`

Note that this is using the old (non-Gogo implementation) and the built-in console is likely to be removed at some point. However, you should consider running with the Gogo shell instead, which is the de-facto standard for future Eclipse and Felix versions.