# See OSGi bundles

Tags: eclipse, cmd, osgi, bundle, equinox

I have Eclipse 3.8.1 and I want to see which OSGi bundles are started so I wrote in **cmd** from eclipse/plugins directory:

```
java -jar org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.1.v20120830-144521.jar -console
```

But nothing happens only empty line

Do I have to install something to see them?

Comment: See the question which I believe has your answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905607/equinox-start-error-console-bundle-is-missed/15764754#15764754

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have eclipse already running then you can access the **Host OSGI Console** from the **Console** view

[image: Host OSGI Console]

**UPDATE**
I think [this](http://devblog.virtage.com/2012/08/osgi-with-equinox-for-beginners-overview/#update-for-equinox-3.8-console-.28part-of-eclipse-4.2-.28juno.29.29) is what you are looking for

```
$ java -Dosgi.bundles=org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.0.0.v20120522-1841.jar@start,org.apache.felix.gogo.command_0.8.0.v201108120515.jar@start,org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.8.0.v201108120515.jar@start,org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.8.0.v201110170705.jar@start -jar org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.1.v20120830-144521.jar -console
```

Comment: Thanks,@shyam but when my Eclipse is shut down how can I see OSGi bundles which are still runing?

Comment: How would any bundles be running if eclipse itself is not running? The OSGI container should be running before you can load any bundles right?

Comment: I don't know,  I thought  that OSGi container can be used without Eclipse installation

Comment: @Xelian Please see the update is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, if I change the jar version to my it works. Thank you @shyam

Answer (score 0):

There are two options. These are as follows:

1. Create a configuration folder and put a config.ini file. Set the below content in the config.ini file:

osgi.console.enable.builtin=true

This will start equinox framework with the default console.

1. Or take the following steps. For details check: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fconsole_shell.htm

Place the necessary bundles in a folder. The bundles are:

```
org.apache.felix.gogo.command_0.8.0v<version>.jar
org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.8.0v<version>.jar
org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.8.0v<version>.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.0.0v<version>.jar
org.eclipse.osgi.jar
```

Create a configuration subfolder and a config.ini file in it.
Add the following entries in the config.ini file:

```
osgi.bundles=./org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.8.0v<version>.jar@start,\
./org.apache.felix.gogo.command_0.8.0v<version>.jar@start,\
./org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.8.0v<version>.jar@start,\
./org.eclipse.equinox.console.jar@start,\
osgi.console.enable.builtin=false
osgi.console=<port>
```

Start the Equinox framework with the following command line: java -jar org.eclipse.osgi.jar