# Bundle Exception while running OSGI framework

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, osgi, bundle

I'm trying to run my bundle as OSGI framework but i got the following output and i don't know where is the mistake:

```
!SESSION 2013-06-25 13:28:45.073 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_21
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -dev file:C:/Users/HP/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/OSGi Framework/dev.properties -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -consoleLog -console

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-06-25 13:28:51.609
!MESSAGE Could not find bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.console
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not find bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.console
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.ConsoleManager.checkForConsoleBundle(ConsoleManager.java:211)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

**> ss OUTPUT:**

```
id  State       Bundle
0   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.2.v20130124-134944
2   ACTIVE      org.hamcrest.core_1.1.0.v20090501071000
3   ACTIVE      org.junit_4.10.0.v4_10_0_v20120426-0900
4   ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.command_0.8.0.v201108120515
5   ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.8.0.v201108120515
6   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.0.0.v20120522-1841
7   ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.8.0.v201110170705
9   ACTIVE      inotify-bundle-core-conf_1.0.0.qualifier
```

Comment: Are you using Eclipse Juno?

Comment: problem resolved in :

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905607/equinox-start-error-console-bundle-is-missed][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905607/equinox-start-error-console-bundle-is-missed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you are running Eclipse Juno, which comes bundled with `OSGi v3.8`, which does not uses the Eclipse in built console, but the console is now contained it's own bundle. You need to add that bundle. That is what your OSGi is complaining about. You also need to add some felix bundle to get the new console run.

In all, at a minimum, you need to select following bundles in your OSGi run configuration:

```
- org.eclipse.osgi
- org.eclipse.equinox.console
- org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime
- org.apache.felix.gogo.shell
```

---

Or, if you want to use the eclipse built in console, you can enable it by passing following VM arguments:

```
-Dosgi.console.enable.builtin=true
```

Comment: thanks, problem solved, now the bundle runs normally but there is another exception appears and  don't know if it will affect any thing or not :

org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Invalid manifest header Import-Package: "org.eclipse.osgi.framework.console;version="1.1.0"" : Cannot import a package more than once "org.eclipse.osgi.framework.console"
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.StateBuilder.checkImportExportSyntax(StateBuilder.java:819)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.StateBuilder.validateHeaders(StateBuilder.java:212)
.
.
.

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat. What is it?

Comment: You don't need that import package. Just remove it.

Comment: the thing is i didn't import it

Comment: Can you post the output of `ss >` command on your question? Just post the OSGi bundles that are installed.

Comment: Run the following command: - `packages org.eclipse.osgi.framework.console` And see what you get.

Comment: i got this when running the command :
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.console; version="1.1.0"<org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.2.v20130124-134944 [0]>
  org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.0.0.v20120522-1841 [6] imports

Comment: That's strange. Everything seems fine to me. I'll check out what might be wrong. Meanwhile, you can use the 2nd option in my answer. Just remove the 4 bundles, and enable the same old console.

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat. Ok. Check if removing the `org.apache.felix.gogo.command` bundle, and keeping the rest 3 solves the problem?

Comment: Guys, don't start an entirely unrelated question and answer chain in the comments! This new manifest problem should be a separate StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue. Was just about to download ggts again. But just deleting. Metadata folder from workspace solved it. But after that u have to import and set all configuration again.