# Could not find bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.console

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle

I'm trying to deploy the Equinox v3.9.1, but I reach the following Exception:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-11-11 12:19:29.027
!MESSAGE Could not find bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.console
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not find bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.console
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.ConsoleManager.checkForConsoleBundle(ConsoleManager.java:211)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.main(EclipseStarter.java:152)
```

I am using the config.ini file as follows:

```
osgi.bundles=org.eclipse.osgi@-1:start ,\
    org.apache.felix.gogo.command@:start, \
    org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime@:start, \ 
    org.apache.felix.gogo.shell@:start, \
    org.eclipse.equinox.console@:start, \
    org.eclipse.equinox.cm@:start, \
    org.eclipse.equinox.common@:start, \
```

I am sure the jar file is in the folder. Could anyone help me to solve this error?

Thank you very much

Comment: possible duplicate of [Equinox start error (console bundle is missed)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905607/equinox-start-error-console-bundle-is-missed)