# gogo: CommandNotFoundException in osg console

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi

I tried many command throuh OSGI console but none of them is executing.

```
osgi> bundle
gogo: CommandNotFoundException: Command not found: bnl
osgi> bnl
gogo: CommandNotFoundException: Command not found: udebl
osgi> udebl
gogo: CommandNotFoundException: Command not found: el
osgi> el
gogo: CommandNotFoundException: Command not found: nudbe
osgi> nudbe
gogo: CommandNotFoundException: Command not found: lnudbe
osgi> lnudbe
gogo: CommandNotFoundException: Command not found: lnudbe
osgi> c
gogo: CommandNotFoundException: Command not found: c
osgi>
```

I am pretty new in OSGI, infact started yesterday itself. I'm reading to a tutorial at 
http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077837/java-se/java-se-hello-osgi-part-1-bundles-for-beginners.html

i followed the article and ran my first hello world program. i got the desired output but with hell lot of exception.

Do i need to make some changes in my eclipse to start plugin development?

Please respond.

Comment: Most of the commands which you've used are invalid. Check the valid commands - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecl-osgiconsole/

Comment: Plain eclipse is not very convenient for OSGi development. You take a look at bndtools and Apache Karaf. Both provide a much nicer environment.

Comment: See the tutorials at http://enroute.osgi.org/

Comment: There is also a section about Gogo in the App Notes: http://enroute.osgi.org/appnotes/gogo.html

Answer (score 0):

`bundle` is an Equinox-specific command provided by the `org.eclipse.equinox.console` bundle.  The console commands are provided by various bundles, but those bundles need to have been started for the commands to be registered.  You can use `help` to see the currently registered commands.

It's likely that you either haven't loaded the `org.eclipse.equinox.console` bundle, or haven't started it. Try the following to start the bundle:

```
osgi> help bundle
osgi> ss org.eclipse.equinox.console
"Framework is launched."


id  State       Bundle
104 RESOLVED    org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.1.200.v20150929-1405
osgi> start 104
osgi> ss org.eclipse.equinox.console
"Framework is launched."


id  State       Bundle
104 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.1.200.v20150929-1405
osgi> help bundle

bundle - display details for the specified bundle(s)
   scope: equinox
   parameters:
      Bundle[]   (<id>|<location>)
```

Equinox doesn't automatically start all bundles by default.  If you're experimenting with running Equinox directly (`java -Dosgi.bundles=bundle1,bundle2,bundle3 -jar …/org.eclipse.osgi_*.jar`), then append `:start` after a bundle to cause it to be automatically started.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i figured it out.
There was nothing wrong with command. I was missing on some libraries that i needed to download and add manually
i followed this [Equinox start error (console bundle is missed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905607/equinox-start-error-console-bundle-is-missed)

Answer given by Dmytro Pishchukhin solved my issue.

Thanks for your suggestions. :)